# Flickering while dragging SKNode using NSPanGestureRecognizer on OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, sprite-kit, uigesturerecognizer

Today I decided to try some of the new shiny (iOS inspired) things added to OS X: gesture recognisers and Sprite Kit. I have setup a NSPanGestureRecognizer to the SKView and I'm using it to drag nodes added to the scene. However, I am seeing a strange flicker when dragging the nodes quickly.

[image: Flicker when dragging quickly.]

The code is incredibly simple, setting up everything in AppDelegate,

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    // Add and scene to the view and create a root node
    hostingView.presentScene(SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 1500.0, height: 1500.0)))
    rootNode = SKNode()

    // A a red circle
    let node = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 50.0)
    node.lineWidth = 5.0
    node.strokeColor = NSColor.whiteColor()
    node.fillColor = NSColor.redColor()
    node.userInteractionEnabled = true
    rootNode?.addChild(node)
    hostingView.scene?.addChild(rootNode!)

}
```

Then implement the gesture recogniser's action method,

```
@IBAction func panAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    // Get the location in the view from the pan gesture recogniser
    let viewPoint = (sender as NSPanGestureRecognizer).locationInView(hostingView)

    // Convert from view -> scene -> root node coordinates
    if let scene = hostingView.scene {

        let scenePoint = hostingView.convertPoint(viewPoint, toScene:scene)

        if let root = self.rootNode {

                let rootNodePoint = scene.convertPoint(scenePoint, toNode: root)
                let node = root.nodeAtPoint(rootNodePoint)
                node.position = rootNodePoint
                println("Drag to point:", NSStringFromPoint(scenePoint))
                return
            }
        }

    println("Node was nil.")
}
```

If want to run this project, [it's on github.](https://github.com/danieljfarrell/DraggingSpritesOSX)

Comment: Have you tried adding the shapeNode directly to the view instead of adding it to a SKNode first?

Comment: Interesting, I think you are on to something. Different problem now, when you do that the, circle stops dragging when the mouse moves outside the nodes bounds. What was happening before, therefore, was that we changed from dragging the circular node to the root node when the mouse was travelling quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the mouse is dragged fast and exits the bounds of the node, `nodeAtPoint:` was returning the background node. This resulted   in the flickering (thanks @sangony).

The solution is to use the [NSGestureRecognizer's state](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014954-CH1-SW11) value to distinguish between the first time it is triggered (`NSGestureRecognizerStateBegan`), an update (`NSGestureRecognizerStateChanged`), and when the mouse is released (`NSGestureRecognizerStateEnded`). By checking these values, the correct node can be cached an updated even if it mouse moves outside of the nodes bounds.

The updated action method is,

```
@IBAction func panAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    // Get the location in the view from the pan gesture recogniser
    let recognizer = (sender as NSPanGestureRecognizer)
    let viewPoint = recognizer.locationInView(hostingView)


    if let scene = hostingView.scene {

        // Convert from view -> scene
        let scenePoint = hostingView.convertPoint(viewPoint, toScene:scene)


        if let root = self.rootNode {

            // Convert from scene -> rootNode
            let rootNodePoint = scene.convertPoint(scenePoint, toNode: root)

            // Use the recogniser state, this keeps track of the correct node
            // even if the mouse has moved outside of the node bounds during
            // the drag operation.
            switch recognizer.state {
            case .Began:

                // Cache the clicked node
                let node = root.nodeAtPoint(rootNodePoint)
                if node != root {
                    node.position = rootNodePoint
                    draggedNode = node
                    return
                }

            case .Changed:

                // Update the cached node position
                if let draggedNode = self.draggedNode {
                    draggedNode.position = rootNodePoint
                }

            case .Ended:

                // Finally update the position and clear the cache
                if let draggedNode = self.draggedNode {
                    draggedNode.position = rootNodePoint
                    self.draggedNode = nil
                }

            default:
                return

            }
        }
    }
}
```